# Ionic Side Menu Not Showing Content

Tags: html, css, angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

I am working on my first ionic/angularjs app and have hit a snag. I can get the page to load like I want with a tabbed navigation and side menu but the content in the side menu won't show for some reason. It is in the page, I can see it in view source but it will not show no matter what manipulation I try to the styling. Being new to this I am at a loss for what to do now. Below is the code.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/user-object.js"></script>
<script src="js/news-feed-object.js"></script>
<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<!-- your controllers js -->
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="wgn">
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-energized nav-title-slide-ios7 ">
    <div ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
    <ion-side-menus>
        <fade-bar></fade-bar>
        <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
            <header class="bar bar-header bar-energized nav-title-slide-ios7">
                <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="openLeft()"><i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>
                </button>
                <h1 class="title">Test App</h1>
            </header>
            <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
                <!-- Center content -->
            </ion-content>
        </ion-pane>
        <ion-side-menu side="left">
            <header class="bar bar-header bar-dark" fade-header>
                <h1>Left</h1>
            </header>
            <ion-content has-header="true">
                <div>Content</div>
                <div>Content</div>
                <div>Content</div>
                <div>Content</div>
                <div>Content</div>
                <div>Content</div>
                <div>Content</div>
                <div>Content</div>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>
</div>
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c ">
    </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-t">
</ion-nav-view>
</body>

</html>
```

tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-energized">
<ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/events">
    <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios7-information" href="#/tab/about">
    <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<ion-tab title="Sign-Out" icon="ion-log-out" href="#/sign-in">
</ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

app.js

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('wgn', ['ionic', 'wgn.controllers', 'wgn.services'])
.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }

        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

    });
})
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('signin', {
        url: "/sign-in",
        templateUrl: "templates/sign-in.html",
        controller: 'SignInCtrl'
    }).state('forgotpassword', {
        url: "/forgot-password",
        templateUrl: "templates/forgot-password.html"
    }).state('slidemenu', {
        url: "/slide-menu.html",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/slide-menu.html'
    }).state('tabs', {
        url: "/tab",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    }).state('tabs.home', {
        url: "/home",
        views: {
            'home-tab': {
                templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
                controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
            }
        }
    }).state('tabs.eventdetails', {
        url: "/eventdetails/:eventid",
        views: {
            'home-tab': {
                templateUrl: "templates/event-details.html",
                controller: 'EventDetailsCtrl'
            }
        }
    }).state('tabs.addevents', {
        url: "/addevents",
        views: {
            'home-tab': {
                templateUrl: "templates/addevents.html"
            }
        }
    }).state('tabs.about', {
        url: "/about",
        views: {
            'about-tab': {
                templateUrl: "templates/about.html"
            }
        }
    }).state('tabs.navstack', {
        url: "/navstack",
        views: {
            'about-tab': {
                templateUrl: "templates/nav-stack.html"
            }
        }
    }).state('tabs.contact', {
        url: "/contact",
        views: {
            'contact-tab': {
                templateUrl: "templates/contact.html"
            }
        }
    });


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/sign-in");

  });
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('wgn.controllers', [])
.controller('SignInCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
    $scope.signIn = function (user) {
        console.log('Sign-In', user);
        $state.go('tabs.home');
    };
}).controller('HomeTabCtrl', function ($scope, WGNEvents, $ionicModal) {
    console.log('HomeTabCtrl');
    $scope.wgnEvents = WGNEvents.all();
    $scope.user = userObject;
    $scope.newsFeedList = newsFeedObjectList;

    //Add Event 
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/addevents.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function (modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
    });
    $scope.addEvent = function () {
        $scope.modal.show();
        console.log('show modal');
    };
    $scope.closeModal = function () {
        $scope.modal.hide();
    };
    //Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $scope.modal.remove();
    });
    // Execute action on hide modal
    $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function () {
        // Execute action
    });
    // Execute action on remove modal
    $scope.$on('modal.removed', function () {
        // Execute action
    });

  }).controller('EventDetailsCtrl', function ($scope, WGNEvents, $stateParams) {
    console.log('EventDetailsCtrl');
    var eventID = $stateParams.eventid;
    console.log('event-id: ' + eventID);
    $scope.wgnEvents = WGNEvents.get(eventID);

    console.log($scope.wgnEvents);
}).controller('HomePageCtrl', function ($scope, WGNEvents, $ionicModal) {
    console.log('HomePageCtrl');
    $scope.getClass = function (score, par) {
        return {
            'below-par': (par - score) > 0,
            'above-par': (par - score) < 0,
            'text-dark': (par - score) == 0
        };
    }
    $scope.getOverUnder = function (score, par) {
        var total = score - par;
        if (total === 0) {
            total = 'E';
        } else if (total > 0) {
            total = '+' + total;
        }
        return total;
    }
}).controller('MenuCtrl', function($scope) {
// Our controller
})

// The fadeBar directive
.directive('fadeBar', function($timeout) {
return {
restrict: 'E',
template: '<div class="fade-bar"></div>',
replace: true,
link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
  // Run in the next scope digest
  $timeout(function() {
    // Watch for changes to the openRatio which is a value between 0 and 1 that says how "open" the side menu is
    $scope.$watch('sideMenuController.getOpenRatio()', function(ratio) {
      // Set the transparency of the fade bar
      $element[0].style.opacity = Math.abs(ratio);
    });
  });
 }
}
});
```

Comment: Probably at same point. Odd coincidence. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415837/what-can-be-shown-in-content-displayed-in-a-ion-nav-view-displayed-from-a-side-m

Comment: can you create a fiddle or a codepen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Side Menus should not be in your ionNavBar container. I've got an example here showing how to use SideMenu, Tabs, and Navigation elements together. You're close, its just some things don't really work well when they are placed in the wrong place.

http://codepen.io/gnomeontherun/pen/EfKgJ

**Markup**

```
 <ion-side-menus>
  <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive nav-title-slide-ios7">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon"><span class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-left"></span></ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-pane>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-dark"></ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content has-header="true">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item href="#/" ng-click="sideMenuController.toggleLeft()">Home</ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>

  <ion-side-menu side="right" >
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-dark" title="Search"></ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content has-header="true">

    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>

<script id="home.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="Home">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
      <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-plus" ng-click="openModal()"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
      <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="openMenu()"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>        
      <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive">
        <ion-tab title="Stooges">
          <h4>The Stooges</h4>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="stooge in stooges" href="#/{{stooge.name}}">{{stooge.name}}</ion-item>
      </ion-list>
          </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="Tab 2">
          <h2>Just another tab, for another reason</h2>
          </ion-tab>
        </ion-tabs>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <div class="modal">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">New Stooge</h1>
      <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="modal.hide()">Cancel</button>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <div class="padding">
        <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Name</span>
            <input ng-model="form.name" type="text" name="name" />
          </label>
          <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="addStooge()">Create</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </div>
</script>

<script id="item.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view title="{{item}}">
    <ion-content>
      <h1>{{item}}</h1>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    .state('item', {
      url: '/:item',
      controller: 'ItemCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'item.html'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $ionicModal) {
  $scope.stooges = [{name: 'Moe'}, {name: 'Larry'}, {name: 'Curly'}];

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal.html', {
    animation: 'slide-in-up',
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function (modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  $scope.openMenu = function () {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  }

  $scope.openModal = function () {
    $scope.modal.show();
  }

  $scope.form = {};

  $scope.addStooge = function () {
    console.log($scope);
    $scope.stooges.push({name: $scope.form.name});
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $scope.modal.remove();
  });

})
.controller('ItemCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
  $scope.item = $stateParams.item;
});
```