# What can be shown in content displayed in a ion-nav-view displayed from a side-menu?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

So, I am still somewhat at the copy-paste-pray stage of learning some of what is going on in these frameworks. But I cannot see what I can or cannot do in the view being navigated to by my side-menu.

Here is the entire page. Any suggestions? I am using Firefox, opening the window to be approximately iPhone shaped and loading the index.html.

I do not want to use old-fashioned table tags. On the other hand, I am not seeing what will work. I want reasonable CSS-style HTML. But the view cannot even show an html table?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">

         <title>AAA</title>

         <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

         <!-- These next two make the app start slow, but this will work until we decide on how to bundle. -rrk -->
         <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.11/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.11/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

         <script type="text/javascript">

             angular.module('aaa', ['ionic'])

             .factory('Calculators', function() {

               return {

                 all: function() {
                   return [
                      { title: "MENU1" },
                      { title: "MENU2" },
                      { title: "MENU3" },
                      { title: "MENU4" },
                      { title: "MENU5" },
                      { title: "MENU6" },
                      { title: "MENU7" }
                   ];
                 },

                 getLastActiveIndex: function() {
                   return parseInt(window.localStorage['lastActiveCalculator']) || 0;
                 },

                 setLastActiveIndex: function(index) {
                   window.localStorage['lastActiveCalculator'] = index;
                 }
               }
             })

             .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
                 "use strict";

                 /* Set up the states for the application's different sections. */
                 $stateProvider
                     .state('MENU1', {name: 'about', url: '/about', templateUrl: 'about.html', controller: 'CalculatorCtrl'})
                     .state('MENU2', {name: 'page2', url: '/page2', templateUrl: 'page2.html', controller: 'CalculatorCtrl'})
                     .state('MENU3', {name: 'page3', url: '/page3', templateUrl: 'page3.html', controller: 'CalculatorCtrl'})
                     .state('MENU4', {name: 'page4', url: '/page3', templateUrl: 'page4.html', controller: 'CalculatorCtrl'})
                     .state('MENU5', {name: 'page5', url: '/page3', templateUrl: 'page5.html', controller: 'CalculatorCtrl'})
                     .state('MENU6', {name: 'page6', url: '/page3', templateUrl: 'page6.html', controller: 'CalculatorCtrl'})
                     .state('MENU7', {name: 'page7', url: '/page3', templateUrl: 'page7.html', controller: 'CalculatorCtrl'})
                 ;
                 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/about');
             })

             .controller('CalculatorCtrl', function($scope, Calculators, $state, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

               // Load or initialize calculators
               $scope.calculators = Calculators.all();
               Calculators.setLastActiveIndex(0);

               // Grab the last active, or the first calculator
               $scope.activeCalculator = $scope.calculators[Calculators.getLastActiveIndex()];

               // Called to select the given calculator
               $scope.selectCalculator = function(calculator, index) {
                 $scope.activeCalculator = calculator;
                 Calculators.setLastActiveIndex(index);
                 $state.transitionTo(calculator.title);
                 $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft(false);
               };

               $scope.toggleCalculators = function() {
                 $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
               };

             });
         </script>

     </head>
     <body ng-app="aaa" ng-controller="CalculatorCtrl">

         <ion-side-menus>

             <!-- Center content -->
             <ion-side-menu-content>
                 <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
                     <button class="button" ng-click="toggleCalculators()">
                         <i>Calc</i>
                     </button>
                     <h1 class="title">AAA</h1>
                 </ion-header-bar>

                 <ion-nav-view class="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>

             </ion-side-menu-content>

             <!-- Left menu -->
             <ion-side-menu side="left">
                 <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
                     Text0
                 </ion-header-bar>
                 <ion-content scroll="false">
                     <ion-list>
                         <ion-item ng-repeat="calculator in calculators"
                                   ng-click="selectCalculator(calculator, $index)"
                                   ng-class="{active: activeCalculator == calculator}">
                             {{calculator.title}}
                         </ion-item>
                     </ion-list>
                 </ion-content>
             </ion-side-menu>

         </ion-side-menus>

         <script id="about.html" type="text/ng-template">
             <ion-view title="About">
                 <ion-content padding="true">
                     <form>
                     <table border="1">
                         <tr>
                             <td><input type="button" value="Save/Load" /></td>
                             <td><input type="button" value="Share" /></td>
                             <td><input type="button" value="Help" /></td></tr>
                         <tr><td colspan="3">
                             Text
                         <tr><td colspan="3">Instructions</td></tr>
                         <tr><td colspan="3">
                             <ol>
                                 <li>text1</li>
                                 <li>text2</li>
                                 <li>text3</li>
                             <ol>
                         </td></tr>
                         <tr><td colspan="3">
                             <i><p>
                             text4
                             </p></i>
                         </td></tr>
                     </table>
                     </form>
                 </ion-content>
             </ion-view>
         </script>

         <script id="page2.html" type="text/ng-template">
             <ion-view title="TITLE1">
                 <ion-content padding="true">
                     <form>
                     <table border="1">
                         <tr>
                             <td><input type="button" value="Save/Load" /></td>
                             <td><input type="button" value="Share" /></td>
                             <td><input type="button" value="Help" /></td>
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                     <table border="1">
                         <tr>
                             <td>Desired</td>
                             <td><input type="text" size="6" value="1.5" /></td>
                             <td>years</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td>&nbsp;</td>
                             <th>CURRENT</th>
                             <th>FUTURE</th>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td>Text5</td>
                             <td> </td>
                             <td> </td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td>Text6</td>
                             <td><input type="text" size="3" value="4"></td>
                             <td><input type="text" size="3" value="1"></td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td>Text7</td>
                             <td><input type="text" size="3" value="20"></td>
                             <td><input type="text" size="3" value="30"></td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td>Text8</td>
                             <td><input type="text" size="3" value="40%"></td>
                             <td><input type="text" size="3" value="40%"></td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td>Text9</td>
                             <td><input type="text" size="3" value="2"></td>
                             <td><input type="text" size="3" value="1"></td>
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                     </form>
                 </ion-content>
             </ion-view>
         </script>

         <script id="page3.html" type="text/ng-template">
             <ion-view title="Page 3">
                 <ion-content padding="true">
                     <h1>PAGE 3</h1>
                 </ion-content>
             </ion-view>
         </script>

         <script id="page4.html" type="text/ng-template">
             <ion-view title="Page 4">
                 <ion-content padding="true">
                     <h1>PAGE 4</h1>
                 </ion-content>
             </ion-view>
         </script>

         <script id="page5.html" type="text/ng-template">
             <ion-view title="Page 5">
                 <ion-content padding="true">
                     <h1>PAGE 5</h1>
                 </ion-content>
             </ion-view>
         </script>

         <script id="page6.html" type="text/ng-template">
             <ion-view title="Page 6">
                 <ion-content padding="true">
                     <h1>PAGE 6</h1>
                 </ion-content>
             </ion-view>
         </script>

         <script id="page7.html" type="text/ng-template">
             <ion-view title="Page 7">
                 <ion-content padding="true">
                     <h1>PAGE 7</h1>
                 </ion-content>
             </ion-view>
         </script>

     </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table elements are reset by the CSS, so you'd have to reapply the all CSS styles you wish for your table. In mobile, they are rarely the item you want.

What you probably want to do is to use the Ionic css grids. http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid You get much the same layout as a table but avoid the use of tables. Tables should not be used for layouts.

Here is your first view redone for you.

```
     <script id="about.html" type="text/ng-template">
         <ion-view title="About">
             <ion-content padding="true">
                 <div class="row">
                   <div class="col"><input type="button" value="Save/Load" /></div>
                   <div class="col"><input type="button" value="Share" /></div>
                   <div class="col"><input type="button" value="Help" /></div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                 <div class="col">Text</div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                 <div class="col">Instructions</div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                 <div class="col">
                   <ol>
                     <li>text1</li>
                     <li>text2</li>
                     <li>text3</li>
                   </ol>
                 </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                 <div class="col">
                   <p><i>text4</i></p>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </ion-content>
         </ion-view>
     </script>
```

Ionic is designed to make things look like the native SDK makes things appear. The CSS reset they use resets everything well, but no additional styles are setup for tables (probably other elements too). The `<ol>` element also lacks styles, because the intent is you will use the `list` component.

Comment: Yes, I suspected that I was just making things difficult for myself by not using the ionic stuff. I was, though, trying to separate out the separate things that are new and that I am still learning. Thanx.